# Concept of comparing numbers with tolerance

Tags: c, conceptual, conceptual-model

I wanted to ask if there is a better way to compare numbers with a tolerance than mine.

Edit: It seems I was way to vague with my explanation.  added some information into the text.
This is concept only until now. I have not programmed any of it yet.

I want to compare around 6000 numbers with each other. The measured numbers [A] are slightly off than the numbers of [B].
[A] are the calculated molar masses of molecules (polymers to be specific). [B] are the measured molar masses of the molecules. Due to measurement errors and isotopes abundance the measured molar masses gradually increase with every added repeating unit of the polymer (= more elements in the molecule, = more offset). The difference in molar masses is relatively small in the lower molar masses (~ 0.1) and can range up to ~10 in the higher ranges. (Also, the numbers in [B] will never be the exact same as the calculated numbers in [A].) The range of the numbers goes from ~100.000000 up to ~76000.000000 (a lot to be precise).
The practical numbers [A] and calculated numbers [B] are written in two different arrays (double) and not sorted.

My goal is to find the closest value of a number in [B] and link it to a number in [A] and mark them as “this molecule”. Every marked number/molecule will not be used again by any other number. One number of [B] only has one matching number in [A] which should be linked/written next to each other. In short, I have to find the number of [B] that fits my number in [A] the best.
(I should also flag numbers when two or more values of [B] are to similar to [A] and not distinguishable. But that is another problem for another time)
My idea for now is, taking one number of [A] and compare it with every number of [B]. The pair with the lowest difference/offset ( Num(A) – Num(B) ) is considered the same and further used.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a function which does this on its own? Do you have suggestions how I could improve this method? Is it bad to use an array of length 6000?

Side information:
I am programming in C
Both practical and theoretical values are stored in an double arrays[6000]
I am saving/writing the data in excel like table structures

Comment: Are the numbers that you want to compare sitting on the same indices in both arrays? What kind of problem are you solving?

Comment: I would sort B. For each value in A, do a binary search in B. The search will either find an exact match, or the location of the two closest numbers in B.

Comment: What result are you trying to accomplish? “Yes or no, all these numbers in A could be the results of floating-point calculations that would have produced the numbers in B if real-number arithmetic were used instead of floating-point arithmetic?” Or “This vector A is pretty close to this vector B?” Or “These numbers in A are suspicious, a human should look them over?” Or “If all of these numbers in A are known to be partners of numbers in B and differ only because floating-point arithmetic was used, which ones in A partner with which ones in B?” What is the range of the numbers?

Comment: There is a very good series on this blog: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/.

Comment: What do the indices mean?  Are the numbers time-series?

Comment: I have edited my question to your demands. I hope this time I could answer all your questions.

Comment: Given your updated description, would sorting each array and matching the elements by resulting position give the best match? I.e., the lowest element in A is matched with the lowest element in B, the second lowest in A is matched with the second lowest in B, and so on. If this is not the best match, it implies that some of the errors/deviations are so great that elements would be swapped in one array (relative to the other or to their ideal positions if the errors were eliminated). If that is the case, there may be no way of solving the problem…

Comment: … For example, if elements Ax and Ay were 897 and 900 and Bp and Bq were 900 and 905, and the underlying situation was that Ax (897) should be matched with Bq (905, an error of 8) and Ay (900) should be matched with Bp (900, an error of 0), the sorting would incorrectly match Ax (897) with Bp (900) and Ay (900) with Bq (905), but how would any algorithm have any way of determining that Ax should match Bq and Ay should match Bp?